# What's the energy produced by a nuclear battery?

Tags: particle-physics, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

I'm currently learning about Radiation in my Physics course, and so far i was interested in betavoltaic batteries that convert eletrons to photons and then eletricity.

I'm confused about how to calculate the energy per second (W) produced by eletrons converted to photons.
Can someone help me on that?

Comment: Do you mean in something like an optoelectric nuclear battery? The typical energy loss of an electron in a luminescing detector is on the order of 20eV per photon, if I remember correctly. Add to that optical losses and the efficiency loss in a typical photoelectric cell with mismatched bandgap (at least another factor of two for silicon devices) and you are down to an efficiency of a few percent, at most. I wouldn't be surprised to learn that practically implemented devices are far below 1%.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_battery      https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betavoltaic_device